# Run Mozart/Oz system within GNU Emacs on OSX instead of Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, oz, mozart

Is it possible to make Mozart/Oz system run within GNU Emacs on OSX instead of Aquamacs which I dislike? I tried copying /Applications/Emacs to /Applications/Aquamacs but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do that. Just started it from command line and standard Emacs 24 (residing in /Applications/Emacs) appeared:

```
$ /Applications/Mozart.app/Contents/Resources/bin/oz
```

[image]

Some magic happens here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the Mozart application uses shell scripts that are hard-coded to look for `/Applications/Aquamacs Emacs.app`. Some of these scripts also attempt to use `/Applications/Aquamacs.app` or `/Applications/Emacs.app`, but do not consistently use both. (This is why [Tvaroh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552608/8116829) works: the script located in `/Applications/Mozart.app/Contents/Resources/bin/oz` is able to use GNU Emacs. It's also why the attempt to change the name of `Emacs.app` to `Aquamacs.app` did not fix the issue. Renaming `Emacs.app` to `Aquamacs Emacs.app` should work, but I'd recommend using the solution written below instead.)

The fix is fairly simple: just modify the shell scripts so that they use Emacs rather than Aquamacs. Entering the following lines in Terminal appears to fix the issue for the latest build (1.4.0-2012-02-01-macosx):

```
$ sed -i '' -e "s/Aquamacs\\\ Emacs/Emacs/g" /Applications/Mozart.app/Contents/Resources/.script
$ sed -i '' -e "s/Aquamacs Emacs/Emacs/g" /Applications/Mozart.app/Contents/Resources/.script
$ sed -i '' -e "s/Aquamacs\\\ Emacs/Emacs/g" /Applications/Mozart.app/Contents/Resources/script
$ sed -i '' -e "s/Aquamacs Emacs/Emacs/g" /Applications/Mozart.app/Contents/Resources/script
```

With that said, I'd encourage anyone who encounters this problem to search their distribution for other offending files (`$ grep -ir aquamacs /Applications/Mozart.app`) and modify those files as necessary to ensure that Mozart will use the correct Emacs.

A couple of notes about this answer for anyone else who comes across this issue:

- For this to work there needs to be an `Emacs.app` in the Applications directory (e.g. just having a the copy of Emacs that comes with macOS/OS X is not sufficient for this solution to work, although it should be possible to edit the scripts within `Mozart.app` to run using that Emacs binary.)
- This issue only exists in builds of Mozart 1.x for macOS/OS X. As of Mozart 2.0.0, the program runs as is, without having to install Aquamacs, as long as some form of Emacs is already located in `/Applications/Emacs.app`.